# Google Connection failing in Electron and Angular 4 with auth0-lock 10.15

Tags: angular, electron, auth0

I have an Electron + Angular 4 application which I am trying to wire with auth0, and I am not having success with the Google connection.

I have

- tried both `Native` and `SPA` Client Types
- set Allowed Callback URLs
- set CORS
- walked through multiple posts
- reviewed multiple repos
- read auth0-lock issues
- tried standard and hash location strategy quickstarts
- tried multiple `options` configurations

What am I missing? I suspect it is something obvious.

Cheers,
Geoffrey

---

Google Fails in Application
[image]

But shows it works in the auth0 logs:
[image]

Twitter Behaves as Expected
[image]

---

**Blog Post**

https://auth0.com/blog/create-a-desktop-app-with-angular-2-and-electron/

**Standard Quickstart (Angular 2)**

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login

**HashLocationStrategy (Angular 2)**

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login#use-with-hashlocationstrategy

**Forum**

https://auth0.com/forum/t/unable-to-login-when-running-app-in-electron/4565/7

**Repos**

https://github.com/faxad/cartify/blob/upgrade/4-0-0/src/app/shared/auth.service.ts

Comment: Some responses in auth0 community: https://community.auth0.com/questions/1900/google-connection-failing-in-electron-and-angular

Comment: No "answer" yet.